# On pageload default a radio button

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have the below code for checkboxes on a page. I need to have both of them checked by default when the page loads. This displays a result of the query. Now when one of the checkbox is unchecked the form needs to be submitted and a different query results needs to be displayed. The checkboes are always being checked even I uncheck one box. Can someone please guide me here? thanks

```
   <form action="abc.cfm?show=yes" method="post" name="myform">
      <table align="center"><tr>
      <td>
     <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="chkbox" id="chkbox1"> <font size="3+"><strong> Agreement      Only</strong> </font>
       &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="chk" id="chk1">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="chkbox" id="chkbox2"> <font size="3+"><strong>Active          Employees</strong> </font>
     &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="chk" id="chk2">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="Submit" name="submitnow" value="View now">
     </td>
        </table>
      </form>

             <cfif isdefined("form.chk1")>
                  query 1
              <cfelseif isdefined("form.chk2")>
                  query 2
             </cfif>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you need to save the selected radio button state? Do you need the state on server-side, or on client-side?

Comment: on the client side...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `<input type="hidden" value=" (the value of your checkbox here) "/>` for storing and then sending the checked value.

Just what exactly do you mean by 'save the selected radio button state' ?

In the page your form is posted to, you will know which checkbox is checked by examining your post variables. If your idea is to display the page with the above code again, with the user-selected checkbox checked, you may take a look at the following (jQuery 1.6+) :

```
$("#chkboxId").prop('checked', true); //check the checkbox with id chkboxId.
$("#chkboxId").prop('checked', false); //uncheck it.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var states = [false, false, true];

function saveStates()
{
    var context = $("#chk1,#chk2,#chk3");
    $(context).each(function (index) {
        states[index] = $(context[index]).prop("checked");
    });
}
```

I didn't test this, maybe there is a syntax error somewhere, but you get the idea. You need to use jQuery to apply my solution.